# How to access C# members that differ in case from inside a vb.net project

Tags: c#, vb.net

This :

```
public class Something
{
    public string lala = "";

    public class Lala
    {
         //...
    }
}
```

is legal C# now I compile it etc and drop the dll in a new Vb.Net project : how do I access member `lala` from VB.Net, if I try I get the error "*'lala' is ambiguous because multiple kinds of members with this name exist in class Something"*.

Comment: Have you created an _instance_ of `Something`?  How have you tried to access it so far.  Also note that VB is not case-sensitive so having a nested class and a field with the same letters but different casing may cause you issues.

Comment: `dim wat as new Something()` and `dim foo = wat.lala`

Comment: I guess I was just being rhetorical [the error you get is : 'lala' is ambiguous because multiple kinds of members with this name exist in class Something] , working in VB.Net on a project and this is the nTh  time I run into this with a 3rd party dll...only solution I know is ISpy, Reflexil and rename the field, recompile...but that's illegal isn't it ;)

Comment: If you followed [the C# naming conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms229043%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) you could not have this problem. All public members are Pascal Cased (start with a captial letter) so `lala` and `Lala` would have had a naming conflict. Also public fields are frowned upon in C#, it really should be a public property `public string Lala {get; set;}` (you will need to do`Lala = "";` in the constructor)

Comment: The field lala or the member Lala?

Comment: @esjr So, you get an error, decide to ask about it online, but *deliberately* not mention the error you're getting, just to make it *harder* for people to help you?

Comment: If you are having problems with a 3rd party DLL, you may find it more useful to limit all your interactions with the 3rd party DLL to a single class library which is written in C#. Then your remaining VB.NET libraries reference your properly written C# library. This also has the benefit of not intermingling the 3rd party DLL code throughout your baseline (which will help if the 3rd party API changes).

Comment: I am well aware of the conventions and what is frowned upon in C#, in fact I think I was doing the frowning : if 'you' [3rd party dll] followed the C# naming conventions 'we' would not be faced with such nonsense ;)

Comment: [Capitalization Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043.aspx) Case Sensitivity section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you're probably going to have to resort to reflection to access this dll.  Once you get your System.Type instance for the 'Something' class (using the 'GetType' instance method of the System.Reflection.Assembly type), you will use the type instance's 'GetField' method to access the 'lala' field and the type instance's 'GetNestedType' method to access the 'Lala' nested type.

```
Imports System.Reflection
...
Dim assembly As Assembly = Assembly.Load(...)
Dim outerType As Type = assembly.GetType("Something")
Dim field As FieldInfo = outerType.GetField("lala")
Dim nestedType As Type = outerType.NestedType("Lala")
```

You would then use field.SetValue(..) and field.GetValue(..) to access the 'lala' field.

Comment: Of course, it you have access to the C# code, then it would be better to just rename either the field or the nested type.

Answer (score 1):

First: Add the reference to your project.

[image: add reference]

Browse to your Something_Lala DLL file and add it.

Next, you need to import that into your file, initialize it, and then use it.

[image: psudo code]

The example code looks bad, but that was all you gave the SO community to work with.